# Minimizing HTTP request

Tags: http

I'm building an application for real estate brokers for which it has a feature to show image galleries for properties they're listing.

By examining several similar sites, I found that they're using two different type of images:

1. Big images: Those images are using to display properties to users
2. Small thumbnail images: Those are using to help users navigating between property big images (act like control buttons).

The thumbnail image and the corresponding bigger image are very similar. The image ratios are the same, only the difference in size.

My question is: Is it better to use only one type of image, for example, big images both for showing and also for navigating. By doing that we reduce number of HTTP request to our server, still delivering same result to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why use thumbnails and bigger pictures?**

1. to cut down request bandwidth
2. decrease load times
3. better user experience

It doesn't really have to do with requests, just download times.  Large images start lagging pages so it's best to deliver them on-demand and not arbitrarily.

Instead of the page having to load 10 20MB images you can load 10 30KB thumbnails.  Once the user clicks the thumbnail, they are demanding to see the larger version. You see the difference?

Comment: I see. Just forgot that big images are loaded in demand. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your welcome check out [this article](http://cloudinary.com/blog/top_10_mistakes_in_handling_website_images_and_how_to_solve_them)